# What was the traditional attire for men and women in the Vedic period?

Tags: vedas, culture

The clothes that we wear can say a lot about our personality. I believe in Vedic period clothing for men and women are different than that of us. If yes, what was the traditional attire for men and women in the Vedic period?

Note: Here I am asking about traditional clothing for men and women in the Vedic period, but not from Scriptures views ([Does Hinduism have specific dress code guidelines in their dharma shastras (scriptures)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/326/does-hinduism-have-specific-dress-code-guidelines-in-their-dharma-shastras-scri)  I'm already read this question there is significant difference). So I hope it might be helpful for people who think this question is already there?

Comment: May be same clothes which is wear by Gods. Cloths which we use to see in pictures of God. Although it is just an opinion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_clothing_in_India#Vedic_period

Comment: The question really sounds very interesting but can't find proper answers apart from these links: [Clothes in vedic times](https://idyllic.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/clothes-in-vedic-times/), [Traditional vedic attire](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-traditional-vedic-attire-for-men-and-women) and [Indian Clothing](http://quatr.us/india/clothing/)

Comment: Asking about personality would make your question too broad, so I'm taking out that part of your question.

Comment: what do you mean by Vedic period ? Even today is Vedic period for those who live by its rules.. The standard attire for brahmin men is pancha-kacha (dhoti) & angavastram, and for women is madisaar (sari). you can check internet for how it looks.

Comment: This Q is not about religion.

Comment: @ram It is a label used in the study of history. (History as defined by the west and that which is about 3k yrs old).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Hinduism have specific dress code guidelines in their dharma shastras (scriptures)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/326/does-hinduism-have-specific-dress-code-guidelines-in-their-dharma-shastras-scri)

Answer (score 2):

In vedic period clothes were different according to persons professions and there were variety.
As seen from the Ramayana and Mahabharata Most of the clothes were without stitch.
People use to wear clothes as whole like Dhoti and sarees.

Comment: Welcome on Hinduism.SE. You should cite sources to back your answer. It looks more like a comment as of now.

Comment: Thanks @TriyugiNarayanMani well i would try to explain what i read so far from various granthas and puranas but on that matter i don't think i have found  an explanation but in GURUCHARTA there you can found information about it.